# Error connecting to firebase after upgrading angularfire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Since upgrading angularfire (to 2.0.1) to support the latest version of Firebase (3.2.0) my app no longer connects to the database. Any ideas why? Here's my simple code that worked before.

```
.constant('FIREBASE_URL', 'https://my_app_url.firebaseio.com/')

.factory('firebaseRef', function($firebase, FIREBASE_URL) {

      var firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

      return firebaseRef;
    })
```

My error is: `ionic.bundle.js:20434 ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined` The error references the above line `var firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Take some time to read [this entire page](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialising firebase is different in SDK 3 and up.

Now there's a global `firebase` (as opposed to `Firebase` constructor) and you need to first initialise it and then you can get a reference to the root of your database.

So your code could look something like this:

```js
ngModule.constant('FIREBASE_CONFIG', {
  apiKey: "apiKey",
  authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com",
});

ngModule.factory('firebaseRef', function($firebase, FIREBASE_CONFIG) {

  firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);
  return firebase.database().ref();
});
```

Checkout [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).

Comment: Thanks, super dumb question here. Why use `ngmodule.` or any prefix at all? Currently my code does not use a name prefix, hence `.constant`  That's the part that's confusing me, if I use `ngmodule.` then do I have to change all my factories and services to use `ngmodule.` as a prefix?

Comment: I think my problem here is a naming / organizing one :)

Comment: It's supposed to be a reference to your existing AngularJS module which you created with `angular.module('your-module', []);`. You can then get this module like so: `var module = angular.module('your-module');`

Comment: Thanks @idan , in app.js it reads `angular.module('yourAppsName', ['ionic', 'yourAppsName.services' ])` and in services.js it reads `angular.module('yourAppsName.services', [])` When I use yourAppsName as you suggested, I still get the error `yourAppsName is undefined`.  confused.

Comment: `var module = angular.module('yourAppsName')` should work and then you can use `module` like in the answer

Comment: It's really hard to understand when the word `module` is being used in so many different contexts. I still don't get it.

Comment: You can use any arbitrary variable name

Comment: you mean add `var module` as a prefix to `angular.module('yourAppsName')` in app.js ? won't that break the rest of the app?

Comment: Can you add a fiddle to your answer? It'll be much more obvious

Comment: sure ok, hard to fiddle a working version as so many folders with libs, but can fiddle the code.

Comment: ok here you go, https://plnkr.co/edit/sYIsRL3LPanOHNSqc4Ax?p=catalogue - check out services.js and app.js, I changed them as you suggested.  I'm confused about the structure, it looks like it's currently really simple and just chains on factories and services etc. It's not a working version btw.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I think you took upon yourself more than you can handle. It seems you miss some basic concepts about Javascript.
Basically when you create a module via `angular.module` if returns a reference to an object which is the angular module. You then can call methods on that object so I just changed it back to how it was: https://plnkr.co/edit/18FCzLwEDJjGiw54AHty

Comment: This still will not make your app work since you didn't attach your module to the DOM, and didn't add your js files to your index.html file

Comment: ok back to square one about integrating the new firebase code. I think what you mean is if I use var module = angular.module('yourAppsName', [}) I then have to rename all my factories etc by adding module as a prefix? @idan

Comment: That's right. The only reason it's in my answer is because you didn't include the module instantiation (or any module reference) in your question

Comment: You're welcome. Are you going to mark thus as the answer? Do you need anything else?